# iOS 13 photo content is cleared during save

Tags: ios, objective-c, ionic-framework, camera, exif

When I take a photo with exif info and I want to save it on the phone, the image is not saved because the content is cleared in the process.

```
CGImageSourceRef sourceImage = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge_retained CFDataRef)self.data, NULL);
CFStringRef sourceType = CGImageSourceGetType(sourceImage);

CGImageDestinationRef destinationImage = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)self.data, sourceType, 1, NULL);
CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destinationImage, sourceImage, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)self.metadata);

ok = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destinationImage);

NSString *extension = self.pickerController.pictureOptions.encodingType == EncodingTypePNG ? @"png":@"jpg";
NSString *filePath = [self tempFilePath:extension];

// save file
if (![self.data writeToFile:filePath options:NSAtomicWrite error:&err]) {
    …
} else {
    …
}
```

The `self.data` is cleared after the function `CGImageDestinationCreateWithData` is called.
The `ok` var will be everytime `NO`.

On iOS 12 the code is working as expected, the issue appears only on iOS13.

For testing I used xCode 11 GM Seed and iOS 13 GM Seed.

Here is the complete code: https://github.com/remoorejr/cordova-plugin-camera-with-exif/blob/master/src/ios/CDVCamera.m#L840

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue.
Here is the fix: https://github.com/vlinde/cordova-plugin-camera-with-exif/commit/99465b4c078bac48f26eb28a90737396e7dfca92

Comment: Alexandru, your fix seems to be working fine. Do you have an idea why CGImageDestinationCreateWithData clears the data?